# Python yield with no argument in try block

Tags: python

I was reading [this](http://dietbuddha.blogspot.com/2012/12/52python-encapsulating-exceptions-with.html) article and it was showing this interesting bit of code:

```
class Car(object):
   def _factory_error_handler(self):
      try:
         yield
      except FactoryColorError, err:
         stacktrace = sys.exc_info()[2]
         raise ValidationError(err.message), None, stacktrace

   def _create_customizer_error_handler(self, vin):
      try:
         yield
      except CustomizerError, err:
         self._factory.remove_car(vin)
         stacktrace = sys.exc_info()[2]
         raise ValidationError(err.message), None, stacktrace

   def _update_customizer_error_handler(self, vin):
      try:
         yield
      except CustomizerError, err:
         stacktrace = sys.exc_info()[2]
         raise ValidationError(err.message), None, stacktrace

   def create(self, color, stereo):
      with self._factory_error_handler():
         vin = self._factory.make_car(color)

      with self._create_customizer_error_handler(vin):
         self._customizer.update_car(vin, stereo)

      return vin

   def update(self, vin, color, stereo):
      with self._factory_error_handler():
         self._factory.update_car_color(vin, color)

      with self._update_customizer_error_handler(vin):
         self._customizer.update_car(vin, stereo)

      return
```

Here, they are yielding with no argument in a `try` block. And then using it within a `with` block. Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: This is the worst sort of Java code transliterated into Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code in the post appears to be wrong.  It would make sense if the various error handlers were decorated with `contextmanager`.  Note that, in the post, the code imports `contextmanager` but doesn't use it.  This makes me think the person just made a mistake in creating the post and left `contextmanager` out of that example.  (The later examples in the post *do* use `contextmanager`.)  I think the code as posted will cause an `AttributeError`, because the various `_error_handler` functions aren't context managers and don't have the right `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.

With `contextmanager`, the code makes sense based on [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

> At the point where the generator yields, the block nested in the with statement is executed. The generator is then resumed after the block is exited. If an unhandled exception occurs in the block, it is reraised inside the generator at the point where the yield occurred.